# how to quit omxplayer without using terminal?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

I have made an application launcher using Tkinter for the raspberry pi.I made the application launcher to start automatically after x loads by placing

**@/usr/bin/sudo /home/pi/myscript.py inside /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.**

And for launching applications from within the python script i'm using the subprocess module.The code for the same is:

```
subprocess.Popen('python /home/pi/script.py')
subprocess.Popen('scratch')
subprocess.Popen('omxplayer -o local /home/pi/video.mp4',shell=True)
```

Now what is happening is that all the processes are running fine i.e all the applications gets launched perfectly and when i'm closing the apps(using the close button or alt+f4) that is also working fine.

But the omxplayer seems to be in full screen mode(though its not covering my entire screen).There is no close button there.Some of the documentations say that there are shortcut keys like q for quit but that also doesn't work.The alt+f4 is also not working and moreover since i'm launching it from within my python script(application launcher) I cannot use the terminal to quit the same.

But when I launch the same video from within the terminal both q and alt+f4 is working (i.e I can use both of them to quit omxplayer).

So can anyone explain why this is happening and how can enable the quit thing for the omxplayer while launching it from within the python script?

Comment: did you tried killing those process raised as `omxplayer` from Python?

Answer (score 1):

omxPlayer doesn't run on your Xwindows. it uses GPU to render itself onto directly in your display. as it doesn't run on Xwindows, it doesn't need or have any close button. moreover, when you start this player it becomes the active window of that application from where you launched it.

currently i am using another parallel application that executes command and run this

> ps -ef | grep /usr/bin/omxplayer | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

command to quit this. i am now working for some better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, omxplayer tends to stay alive after playing a sound file. I found out omxplayer tends to have problems with certain TTYs. There is the option `--no-keys` which seems to make omxplayer quit after playing the file. Example:

```
omxplayer --no-keys your_sound_file.mp3
```